# Get all user trades using Binance API

Tags: python, api, binance

I would like to know how i could get the list of previous orders (whatever the symbol) performed by a binance user sorted by timestamp ?

I noticed that there is a function *get_my_trades* which allow to have a the list of previous trades for a specific symbol, but I did not find anything which provide all the symbols trades list.

Thanks